# gitlink won't commit changes?

Tags: packages, gitlink

I load the [GitLink package](https://github.com/WolframResearch/GitLink).

```
Needs["GitLink`"]
```

create a repository

```
localRepository=GitInit[
    "C:\\Users\\atfai\\Desktop\\Version Control System\\test"
]
```

after adding a file in the repository, i add the file so it can be committed

```
GitAdd[localRepository,"*"]
```

I try to commit my changes

```
GitCommit[localRepository,"commit message",<|
    "Name"->"myName",
    "Email"->"myEmail"|>]
```

I get the following error:

> GitCommit::notree: GitLink failed to create a valid commit because the tree was invalid.

What is going on?

Comment: You forgot `"CommitterSignature" ->` but it won't help anyway. It works without that option/3rd argument though.

Comment: Any idea what the error means then in my case?

Answer (score 3):

*Longer comment, I can be wrong too.*

```
(*init code*) 
Needs@"GitLink`"

SetDirectory @ $TemporaryDirectory
CreateDirectory @ "newRepoX"; SetDirectory @ "newRepoX"
repo = GitInit @ Directory[]
GitCommit[repo, "init"]

Put[1, "file.m"]
GitAdd[repo, "*"]
```

I think it is worth creating an [issue](https://github.com/WolframResearch/GitLink/issues) but I would not count on a quick answer.

It seems that `"CommitterSignature"` and `"AuthorSignature"` have not effect except of breaking evaluation for a short syntax for `GitCommit`.

If you use full syntax it will pass but without any effect:

```
commit = GitCommit[
  repo, "commit message", Automatic, "HEAD"
, "CommitterSignature" -> <|"Name" -> "not_me", "Email" -> "randomEmail@gmail.com"|>
]

Dataset@GitProperties@commit
```

[image]

Comment: Now i am getting a different error using your syntax: `GitCommit::badcommitish: GitLink expected a valid commit specification.`

I am using: `GitCommit[
 localRepository,
 "commit messagel",
 Automatic,
 "HEAD",
 "CommitterSignature"-><|
  "Name"->"myName",
  "Email"->"myEmail@hotmail.com"
 |>
]`

Comment: @user13892 probably an initiall commit is needed, let me add a code

Comment: the initial commit through the following error:
`GitCommit::nodefaultusername: GitLink failed to create a valid commit because there is no default username. Configure a username in git by calling, e.g., 'git config --global user.name "John Doe"', and 'git config --global user.email "johndoe@example.com".`

Is there a way to configure git to give it name and email so it does not ask again. My `GitSignature[localRepository]` returns `$Failed`

Comment: @user13892 I think you need to use terminal or git gui.